# Showing different coloured Pins for different Zipcode

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have multiple Zipcode and I want to display different colored pins for different zipcode. Say  am displaying 3 locations New York, CHicago, Boston in my map and I want to display Blue colored pin for New York, Green colored pin for Boston and Red colored pin for Chicago. Can somone provide me the answer how to achieve that using Google Map Javascript v3 API?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the definition of the Marker is the icon.  Just assign the appropriate icon to each marker.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                 {position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long), 
                  icon: 'path/to/your/icon.png'}
             );
```